How can I reference a section in an appendix as "section A.1" using cleveref?
MWE:
\documentclass[twoside=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is the introduction chapter. See \cref{sec:intro/section} for important details.

\section{Import Details}\label{sec:intro/section}
This section contains important details.

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}
This is the first appendix. See \cref{sec:appendix/section} for unimportant details.

\section{Unimportant Details}\label{sec:appendix/section}
This section contains unimportant details.

\end{document}

This results in the following compilation:


However, I want the latter reference to read instead as:

This is the first appendix. See appendix section A.1 for unimportant details

How can I achieve this (idiomatically), and what is the reason why this is not by default as I desire? I noticed that when using scrartcl with sections instead of chapters, and subsections instead of sections, cleveref labels the subsection in the appendix correctly as "subsection". Could this even be a bug in the package?

Adaptations

add \crefalias{subappendix}{section} to your preamble
(reduced code)

Code
\documentclass[twoside=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefalias{subappendix}{section}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}\label{sec:appendix}
This is the first appendix (\cref{sec:appendix}). See \cref{sec:appendix/section} for unimportant details.

\section{Unimportant Details}\label{sec:appendix/section}
This section contains unimportant details.

\end{document}

Result

